# TinyMCE wont show on Firefox, works in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, tinymce

I'm using `TinyMCE` version 4.0.6 and it works fine in `IE9` but in `Firefox` it shows nothing, not even the `textarea` it's connected to.

My code is like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Styles/CSS/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/Addons/TinyMCE/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ]
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
         <textarea name="content" ></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
textarea {
    width:100%;
    min-width:290px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Related, but not an answer to the question: You probably should not be using a `~` to reference files on a website. Use a relative path from where the html file is for best results.

Comment: Also, are you getting any errors in your javascript console, or no errors and it just doesn't show up?

Comment: No errors at all. It just wont show in FF

Comment: I've got a fiddle with your code working in chrome and firefox. The only thing I needed to do to make this work was remove "moxiemanager", that was causing errors: http://jsfiddle.net/4VZZU/

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! I'll add this as an answer so you can mark it solved if anyone else is checking this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue here was with a TinyMCE plugin called MoxieManager, which was not loaded correctly and was causing issues across browsers. When this was removed, it began working across all browsers.

Here's a jsfiddle reproduction of OP's setup that works: http://jsfiddle.net/4VZZU

And here's the modified `plugins` array:

```
plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
```